# The example related just for one sampler for "throughput shaping timer" does not give much idea in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i want to use the Throughput shaping timer for my project in Jmeter to set the "requests per seconds" to any level that i want. i read the article below.

(RPS : requests per second)

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin

it is useful but not sufficient the uses in real life. anyone doesnt send only one sampler. in my project i send a lot of samplers (http requests) and i want to set the RPS for all samplers in total.

for example if there are 20 samplers and i want set the RPS to 100. what jmeter does now?
should i bring the all samplers under the Throughput shaping timer or what?
i tried this method but i coudnt achieve the numbers even if i increase the number of threads (this was be performed in the article).

Answer (score 0):

1. [JMeter Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so it's sufficient to add a single Timer and it will apply the desired throughput to all Samplers it its scope. A good position would be a direct child of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Throughput Shaping Timer per se can only **pause** JMeter threads to **limit** execution rate to the given number of requests per second. If you don't have enough threads in order to conduct the required load - it won't be able to do anything about it so either go for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and connect it to the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) or increase the number of threads so it would be enough in order to deliver the load.

   Also remember 2 constraints:

   - JMeter itself should be able to send requests fast enough so make sure that you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms or CPU, RAM, etc.
   - System under test should be able to respond fast enough as JMeter will wait for the previous response before sending the next request and in case of increased response times the throughput will go down